# TYPO3 logger->log does not do anything

Tags: logging, typo3

I would like to log into Typo3's Administration protocoll (sys_log table) from my plugin.
This is what I have:

```
//classes/controller/MyExtensionController.php
Class MyExtensionController {
    public function doAction() {
        $logger = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Log\\LogManager')->getLogger(__CLASS__);
        $logger->info('TEST', ['something'=>123]);
    }
}
```

I don't get any error, but there is no entry in the sys_log Table.

Answer (score 1):

The [logging framework](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Logging/Index.html) does **not** automatically write into the database table `sys_log` which can be viewed in the Backend Log module. those are 2 different things (in future versions those will be more coupled again).

If you want to write into the `sys_log` table, you need to configure a [Database Writer](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Logging/Writers/Index.html#databasewriter).

Comment: Thanks. Is this a possible way to go for an extension? I mean, will I have to add the configuration to the GLOBALS variable for the whole installation?

Comment: I would prefer the FileWritter as it does not pollute the database and by using `logFileInfix` you get a dedicated log file just for your extension which is easy to grep, watch, ...

Comment: I'll wait for Typo3 V25, when developers decide to provide a logging function. So far I will use file_put_contents. ;-)

Comment: In Wordpress: wc_get_logger()->log('info', $strg); --> in Typo3 a fiddly nightmare.

Comment: as always: please use the tool which fits best. I am not so sure if I can use the same code to log warnings to sentry, debugs messages to a log file and configurable for every extension or class or psr-4 namespace a bit different.